# Probability of coin streaks using python's lists

Tags: python, probability

I tried to write a program to find out how often a streak of six heads or a streak of six tails comes up in a randomly generated list of heads and tails, but my result was absurd (I got 150% whereas other people got around 80%). I tried to compare my program with others, but never understood where I went wrong. Can you please point out to me what's wrong?

```
import random
TotalStreaks = 0
for experimentNumber in range(10000):
    # Code that creates a list of 100 'heads' or 'tails' values.
    explist = []
    numberOfStreaks = 0
    for value in range(100):
        if random.randint(0,1) == 0:
            explist.append('H')
        else:
            explist.append('T')

    # Code that checks if there is a streak of 6 heads or tails in a row.
    for i in range(95): #we are comparing the value of the next 5 values so we want the range to be 100-5

        #compare the element i with the next five elements to see if they match

        if explist[i] == explist[i+1] == explist[i+2] == explist[i+3] == explist[i+4] == explist[i+5]:

            #see if it's the first streak (a.k.a. numberOfStreaks == 0) or
            #if i is not equal to the 5 indexes that follow the most recent index of a streak 

            if numberOfStreaks == 0 or i not in rep:
                numberOfStreaks+=1

                #rep is the list of the indexes of the 5 numbers following the number i
                #which is where the streak was identified

                rep = [i+1, i+2, i+3, i+4, i+5]
                
    TotalStreaks += numberOfStreaks
                
print('Chance of streak: %s%%' % ((TotalStreaks / 10000) * 100))
```

Comment: Why not use `0` and `1` in the list rather than `H` and `T`? That way, `sum(explist[i:i+6])` being equal to either 0 or 6 tells you if it is all 0 or all 1. There is also a definition question. Is `THHHHHHHT` a streak of 6 heads or a streak of 7 heads?

Comment: Your code is basically sound, but what you are calculating is the average number of streaks in your series (which comes out at about 1.5). The problem arises only at the end when you then multiply by 100% and describe it as a probability.

Comment: @JohnColeman You are right I could've used 0 and 1 (that's my mistake, it would save lines of code), however summing up 6 consecutive values doesn't seem a very good idea, because if I happen to have 8 consecutive tails, I'd end up considering 3 streaks, when in reality I only have 1.

Comment: Why not show us your comparison? What are your results, what are the results of others?

Comment: @superbrain my result is 150% and the result that others tend to have is around 75% to 80%

Comment: Would be good to edit that into the question. Just wrote my own, btw, getting about 81%.

Comment: Could you share it @superbrain please?

Comment: @AnaFerreira `import re, random; sum(bool(re.search(r'(.)\1{5}', ''.join(random.choices('HT', k=100)))) for _ in range(10000)) / 100`

Comment: @JohnColeman I believe that includes one streak of 6 heads. It doesn't really matter if it has 7 consecutive heads seen as we are evaluating if it has 6 consecutive heads or not. By definition, I think you mean if I consider 2 streaks of 6 in that sequence or 1. I don't consider a streak if the values have indexes that coincide with those of a previous streak. Hence the use of the list rep. But I would consider 2 streaks if there were 12 consecutive heads.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in the last statement

If you change the last statement with the below statement:

```
print('Chance of streak: {:.2f}%'.format((TotalStreaks / 10000) * 100))
```

I also made some minor changes in the code, without changing the logic.

```
import random

rep = []
TotalStreaks = 0
for experimentNumber in range(10000):
    # Code that creates a list of 100 'heads' or 'tails' values.
    explist = []
    numberOfStreaks = 0
    for value in range(100):
        if random.randint(0, 1) == 0:
            explist.append('H')
        else:
            explist.append('T')

    # Code that checks if there is a streak of 6 heads or tails in a row.
    for i in range(95):  # we are comparing the value of the next 5 values so we want the range to be 100-5

        # compare the element i with the next five elements to see if they match

        if explist[i] == explist[i + 1] == explist[i + 2] == explist[i + 3] == explist[i + 4] == explist[i + 5]:

            # see if it's the first streak (a.k.a. numberOfStreaks == 0) or
            # if i is not equal to the 5 indexes that follow the most recent index of a streak

            if numberOfStreaks == 0 or i not in rep:
                numberOfStreaks += 1

                # rep is the list of the indexes of the 5 numbers following the number i
                # which is where the streak was identified
                
                rep.append(i + 1)
                rep.append(i + 2)
                rep.append(i + 3)
                rep.append(i + 4)
                rep.append(i + 5)

    TotalStreaks += numberOfStreaks

print('Chance of streak: {:.2f}%'.format((TotalStreaks / 10000) * 100))
```

Here is the output:

```
Chance of streak: 80.61%
```

Comment: Hey @Ahmet Tavli, first thanks for your answer! I just have one question about one of your changes: if you append values to the list rep you don't eliminate the ones that were there before, so when you repeat the experiment won't you skip some values seen as they are saved in the rep list from previous iterations?